# Org export: Export org tables to HTML or text files

Tags: emacs, export, org-mode

I have the following table in my org file

```
| Group               | KR # | Tag       | Glossary | Attrib |
|---------------------+------+-----------+----------+--------|
| OXF_PROFILE RSP     | 23   | N_AC_1533 |          | VAL    |
|                     | 23   | N_AC_1549 |          | UNITS  |
|                     | 23   | N_AC_1548 |          | VAL    |
|                     | 23   | N_AC_1553 |          | VAL    |
|                     | 23   | N_AC_1549 |          | VAL    |
|                     | 23   | N_AC_1536 |          | VAL    |
|                     | 23   | N_DC_1722 |          | VAL    |
|                     | 23   | N_DC_1700 |          | VAL    |
|---------------------+------+-----------+----------+--------|
```

When I export this table along with other text in my org file to either as HTML or as a text file, the vertical lines (which marks the columns) in the table are missing.

I see something like this.

```
   Group                KR #  Tag        Glossary  Attrib 
  --------------------------------------------------------
   OXF_PROFILE RSP       23   N_AC_1533            VAL    
                         23   N_AC_1549            UNITS  
                         23   N_AC_1548            VAL    
                         23   N_AC_1553            VAL    
                         23   N_AC_1549            VAL    
                         23   N_AC_1536            VAL    
                         23   N_DC_1722            VAL    
                         23   N_DC_1700            VAL    
  --------------------------------------------------------
```

**Questions**

1. Is there anyway (or `#+OPTIONS:`) that I could pass so that the
   exported output has the vertical lines of the table?
2. Are there any options to make the header row repeat at the end of a page? (In cases where the export is to PDF - I think the concept of pages will apply)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first question, Try Column groups
http://orgmode.org/manual/Column-groups.html

```
| Group           | KR # | Tag       | Glossary | Attrib |
|-----------------+------+-----------+----------+--------|
| /               |   <> | <>        | <>       | <>     |
| OXF_PROFILE RSP |   23 | N_AC_1533 |          | VAL    |
|                 |   23 | N_AC_1549 |          | UNITS  |
|                 |   23 | N_AC_1548 |          | VAL    |
|                 |   23 | N_AC_1553 |          | VAL    |
|                 |   23 | N_AC_1549 |          | VAL    |
|                 |   23 | N_AC_1536 |          | VAL    |
|                 |   23 | N_DC_1722 |          | VAL    |
|                 |   23 | N_DC_1700 |          | VAL    |
|-----------------+------+-----------+----------+--------|
```

If you want to export to PDF by Latex, you can also try to add the following line above your table:

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :align |c|c|c|c|c|
```

The `|c|c|c|c|c|` part is called `table spec` in Latex. Check  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables for explanation.

For your second question, I believe `longtable` can solve it.

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment longtable
```

Check http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-specific-attributes.html for details.
This wiki https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Table_across_several_pages also helps